# Handling "Conflicting Setter Definitions" with Jackson in Jersey for Overloaded Methods

Tags: java, json, jackson, jaxb, jersey

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am encountering an issue with Jackson in a Jersey-based application, specifically dealing with "Conflicting setter definitions for property" error related to overloaded setter methods. Despite using `@JsonIgnore` and `@XmlTransient` annotations, the problem persists.

**Issue Description:**
When Jersey processes requests, it fails with the error "Conflicting setter definitions for property" due to multiple overloaded setter methods. Two of these methods are annotated with `@JsonIgnore` and `@XmlTransient`, but they seem to be ignored.

**Example Code:**
Here's a simplified version of my class with overloaded setter methods:

```java
public class MyEntity {
    private String data;

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlTransient
    public void setData(CustomType1 data) {
        this.data = data.toString();
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlTransient
    public void setData(CustomType2 data) {
        this.data = data.toString();
    }

    // Other fields and methods...
}
```

Comment: If your Jackson annotations aren't working, then it's possible Jackson is not being used as the JSON provider. If you are using Jersey, and you have other providers on the classpath, it might take precedence over Jackson, unless you explicitly register the JacksonFeature.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the following annotation to the good `setData` method : `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter`

According to javadoc, the `@JsonSetter` is :

> Annotation that can be used to define a non-static, single-argument method to be used as a "setter" for a logical property as an alternative to recommended JsonProperty annotation; or (as of 2.9 and later), specify additional aspects of the assigning property a value during serialization.

If not working, try the `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`, which also is documented as follow :

> Marker annotation that can be used to define a non-static method as a "setter" or "getter" for a logical property (depending on its signature), or non-static object field to be used (serialized, deserialized) as a logical property.

If not working, then maybe Jersey is ignoring your Jackson annotations, try registering the `org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature` in your application context.

Comment: Thank you, already tried to do that  with no success.

Comment: New solution proposed above with @JsonProperty annotation

Comment: Also tried, the problem seems more related to the Jersey part

Comment: Maybe the problem is that jersey is ignoring Jackson annotations. Did you try adding [JacksonFeature](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/2.x/media/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.java) to tell Jersey about Jackson JSON ? Updated answer this way :)